# function as class in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, class, object

I am trying to use something similar to Objects/Classes in JavaScript. I found out that this can be done via a function.
So my class code is like this: (using jQuery)

```
function InfoBox(Box) { // My class
    this.Box = Box; // html element
    this.Text = 'Information here';
    this.Image = 'foo.png';

    setText = function () {
        this.Box.children('.Text').html(this.Text);
    }
}
```

The variables in the function work fine but whenever I call the method/function "setText" via

```
var iBoxUser = new InfoBox($('.iBoxUser'));
iBoxUser.Text = 'Welcome';
iBoxUser.setText(); // Error occurs here
```

I get the error: "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

It seems that I'm somehow doing the function thing wrong. Or can functions even contain other functions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change

```
setText = function () {
```

To:

```
this.setText = function () {
```

Update: As comments say, you could also set the function outside your Infobox:

```
InfoBox.prototype.setText = function () {
```

Comment: Better yet, move `setText` outside the function, and write `InfoBox.prototype.setText =`

Comment: I am so stupid. Can you beleve that I was searching for the error for 3 days now?
You saved my day! Thank you a lot!

Comment: @user2334932 happens to the best of us! Next time try to ask for help after just 1 day ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are experiencing a scope problem, what you are doing here is that you set the global variable `setText` to a function expression (it may or may not exist at the moment you declare it). This kind of errors can be avoided by setting [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode).

To expose setText as a method I suggest you to attach it to the [prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype) of `InfoBox`

```
function InfoBox(Box) { // My class
    this.Box = Box; // html element
    this.Text = 'Information here';
    this.Image = 'foo.png';
}

InfoBox.prototype.setText = function () {
    this.Box.children('.Text').html(this.Text);
}
```

Comment: ok thank you. I've seen this prototype already but thought its a member of the function. Now I see that this is an internal member of every JS object. thx